# Synchronizing FTP remote and FS (or HDFS) using Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache, scala, ftp, apache-camel

My requirements are as follow.

From time to time, I want to manually run a tool that would synchronize FTP remote with my FS (at least, ultimately - HDFS) remote.
Each file should be downloaded, newer files should be appended.

I used Apache Camel FTP2 Example:
https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-ftp
to kick off the project. With help from other sources, this is a simple solution.

```
object Main{

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val context = new DefaultCamelContext
    context.addRoutes(FtpRoute())

    context.start
    Thread.sleep(100000)
    context.stop
  }    
}

case class FtpRoute() extends RouteBuilder {

  def configure(): Unit = { // configure properties component
    val pc = getContext.getComponent("properties", classOf[PropertiesComponent])
    pc.setLocation("classpath:ftp.properties")

    val ftpSource = getContext.resolvePropertyPlaceholders(
      s"ftp://{{ftp.serv}}{{ftp.path}}?username={{ftp.user}}&password={{ftp.pass}}&passiveMode=true")

    from(ftpSource)
      .to("file:/tmp/ftp")
      .log("Downloaded file ${file:name} complete.")
  }
}
```

And I could say it works, but... definitely NOT how I would like it to.

1. How to track files progress, and (maybe) stop `Camel` context when all files are downloaded? Do I have to handle it separately?
2. Files from `FTP` are being downloaded over and over again. Non-stop. Why does he keep redownloading the files?
3. A lot of FTP connections are being created. `disconnect=true` did not help here. Do you have any experience with that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**ftp** component is polling consumer.

Such component polls an URI every **delay** мilliseconds.

Every poll, component takes all new files, from first to last.
That's why you see a constant redownloading of files. After downloading all files, the component will stop and will wait until a new event issued by a  timer or schedule.

1. You have to use a Idemponent consumer EIP (http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html). 
   I recommend you use JDBC idemponent consumer. SQLite is my favorite.

My ftp options:

```
disconnect=true&
connectTimeout=300000&
ftpClient.dataTimeout=300000&
timeout=300000&soTimeout=300000&
delay=3600000&reconnectDelay=10000&
backoffErrorThreshold=1&
maximumReconnectAttempts=3&
backoffMultiplier=2&
passiveMode=true&
noop=true&
idempotent=true&
idempotentRepository=#jdbcDocFileIdempotentRepository&
download=true&
recursive=true&
stepwise=true&
antInclude=**/currMonth/*.zip&antExclude=**/prevMonth/*.zip&
idempotentKey=${file:onlyname}-${file:size}
```

And idempotent consumer:

```
<bean id="jdbcDocFileIdempotentRepository"
      class="org.apache.camel.processor.idempotent.jdbc.JdbcMessageIdRepository">
    <argument ref="embeddedDataSource"/>
    <argument value="DocFileRepo"/>
    <property name="tableExistsString" value="SELECT 1 FROM MESSAGE_REPOSITORY WHERE 1 = 0"/>
    <property name="createString" value="CREATE TABLE MESSAGE_REPOSITORY (processorName TEXT, messageId TEXT, createdAt TIMESTAMP, result TEXT)"/>
    <property name="queryString" value="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MESSAGE_REPOSITORY WHERE processorName = ? AND messageId = ?"/>
    <property name="insertString" value="INSERT INTO MESSAGE_REPOSITORY (processorName, messageId, createdAt) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"/>
    <property name="deleteString" value="DELETE FROM MESSAGE_REPOSITORY WHERE processorName = ? AND messageId = ?"/>
</bean>
```

Datasource:

```
<bean id="embeddedDataSource" class="org.sqlite.javax.SQLiteConnectionPoolDataSource">
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:${embedded_db_config_path}" />
   <property name="encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
   <property name="journalMode" value="WAL"/>
</bean>
```

2. You need to set a suitable delay, it needs to be much greater than that by default.
3. If the delay is large enough, then the connections will be closed via timeout. And of course you can adjust the timeout.

UPDATED

According to Camel documentation:

*Option:* **idempotent**=true

Option to use the Idempotent Consumer EIP pattern to let Camel skip already processed files. Will by default use a memory based LRUCache that holds 1000 entries. If noop=true then idempotent will be enabled as well to avoid consuming the same files over and over again.

*Option:* **idempotentRepository**

A pluggable repository org.apache.camel.spi.IdempotentRepository which by default use **MemoryMessageIdRepository** if none is specified and idempotent is true.

So, by default, **ftp** uses the in-memory solution

Comment: So I need a database to tell camel what files were downloaded? Is there no In-memory solution? but not h2 db.

Comment: @Atais MemoryIdempotentRepository is the default solution, but if you restart your camel context, you will lose all previously downloaded file keys. By default, it contains the last 1000 keys. Also you can use FileIdempotentRepository and many others  (full list of solutions you can find here: http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html).

Comment: @Atais I've expanded my answer.